# Button Press in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, font-awesome

I'm using flask for my application and I want a div to appear when the user presses on one of the selected buttons. While this works for every button, the "liking feature" only works for the div in the first button. There is an unfilled heart favicon that I swap for a filled in one when the user presses the heart. However, this only works for the first div and not the rest and I can't seem to know why.

```js
function like(status) {
  console.log("here");
  if (status == 'True') {
    console.log(status);
    document.getElementById('nofill').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('fill').style.display = "inline-block";
  } else if (status == 'False') {
    console.log(status);
    document.getElementById('fill').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('nofill').style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

function showInfo(tag, button_id) {
  console.log("Got to the actions.js file");
  console.log(button_id);
  var selected_tag_div = document.getElementById(tag);
  var button = document.getElementById(button_id);
  if (selected_tag_div.style.display === "none") {
    selected_tag_div.style.display = "block";
    selected_tag_div.style.textAlign = "left";
    // selected_tag_div.style.backgroundColor = "#5BC0DE";
    button.style.opacity = .7;
    selected_tag_div.style.height = "100px";
  } else {
    selected_tag_div.style.display = "none";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "#5BC0DE";
    button.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
{% if output %}
<p class="section-title">Top #'s to use</p>
<div class="output-container text-center">
  {% for tag in output %} {% set button_id = tag[1:] + "-btn" %}
  <button type="button" onclick="showInfo('{{tag[1:]}}', '{{button_id}}')" id={{button_id}} class="btn btn-info tag_buttons">{{tag}}
                                </button>
  <div class="selected-container row" id={{tag[1:]}} style="display: none">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="like-button">
        <span style="float: right;" onclick="like('True')"><i id='nofill' class="far fa-heart" style="color: #000000; font-size:1.5em; display: inline-block"></i></span>
        <span style="float: right;" onclick="like('False')"><i id='fill' class="fas fa-heart" style="color: #FF0000; font-size:1.5em;"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML tag id attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) must be unique so you are not supposed to have elements with the same id in the `DOM`.

```
<span style="float: right;" onclick="like('True')"><i id='nofill' class="far fa-heart" style="color: #000000; font-size:1.5em; display: inline-block"></i></span>
<span style="float: right;" onclick="like('False')"><i id='fill' class="fas fa-heart" style="color: #FF0000; font-size:1.5em;"></i></span>
```

One option is to use `class attribute` instead of id:

```
<span style="float: right;" onclick="like('True')"><i class='nofill' class="far fa-heart" style="color: #000000; font-size:1.5em; display: inline-block"></i></span>
<span style="float: right;" onclick="like('False')"><i class='fill' class="fas fa-heart" style="color: #FF0000; font-size:1.5em;"></i></span>
```

Also look at how to use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword and learn more about [JS events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).